# EF Query: Give .Contains() a combination of two elements to act upon when getting the information from a Database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to optimize the following method by having it return only the data my program actually needs for its calculations.  In the past the dataset hasn't been that large so I haven't needed to optimize this too much.  More recently, my dataset grew from about 30k records to 700k records, so I'm trying to optimize this further.

```
    public void readRawThresholdsInList(int inputtedESourceID, DateTime maxDateTimeVal, List<int> hashKey)
    {
        log.Info("Reading in raw thresholds from db");
        using (FAI db= new FAI ())
        {
            rawThresholds = (from thr in db.Thresholds
                             where thr.CalculatedDate == maxDateTimeVal
                             where thr.ErrorSourceId == inputtedESourceID
                             where hashKey.Contains(thr.HashKey)
                             select thr).ToList();
        }
        log.Info("Read in " + rawThresholds.Count() + " threshold records for error source id: " + inputtedESourceID + ".");

    }
```

I got the method to return about 200k rows from 700k by adding the hashKey.Contains(thr.HashKey), but I want to take this one step further by doing the contains on a combination of 2 fields instead of just 1.  The catch is that this has to happen on the DB for it to improve my runtimes. There is already post processing that only acts on the rows the program will need.

I want to be able to give the method the following as an input and have the contains (or something similar) act on the new HashKeyHostId object:

```
public HashKeyHostId{public int hashKey; public int hostId;} 
public void readRawThresholdsInList(int inputtedESourceID, DateTime maxDateTimeVal, List<HashKeyHostId> hashKeyHostIdPairs){
}
```

There's probably a very simple way of doing this that I'm not thinking of.

Edit:
In response to James's comment - I don't believe this would work. The hashkey variable would now be an object containing pairs of integers instead of just 1 integer.  This alone would prevent you from doing a .contains because it's no longer a primitive. It'd be the "public HashKeyHostId{public int hashKey; public int hostId;}" object I posted above. The new requirement is that a hashkey/hostId combo have to match up to 1 record in the DB.

If you're suggesting I do what Janne said (give it a list of hash keys and a list of host ids), I'm fairly certain this would return all results where the hashkey belongs to any of the hostids in the second list (aka, any combination of the two lists).  I need it to only return rows with the specified combinations, not combinations of anything in the two lists.

Edit2: Sample dataset:
Hashkeys = 100,101,102,103
HostIds = 1,2,3,4,5,6,...,10000

I'd give it a list like

```
List<HashKeyHostId> data = new List<HashKeyHostId>()
{new HashKeyHostId(100,1),new HashKeyHostId(101,5)}
```

I believe the query Janne/James are suggesting would return records for any of those combinations (100,1; 100,5; 101,1; 101,5;). I need it to only return records for 100,1 and 101,5.

edit3:
I tried doing a where hashkeyHostIdpair.Any(o=> o.hashkey==thr.HashKey && o.hostid==thr.HostId)", but that errored out with the same "Unable to create a constant value of type 'RTM_DB.HashKeyHostId'. Only primitive types are supported in this context." message. It doesnt look like you can do a .Any or a .contains on a list of non-primitive types.  I even tried making my own .Any with a where clause and that threw the same exception.  (where hashkeyHostIdpair.Where(o=>o.hostid==thr.HostId && o.hashkey==thr.HashKey).Count()>0))

edit4:  Per Josh's suggestion I tried this:

```
rawThresholds=fai.Thresholds.Where(o=>o.CalculatedDate==maxDateTimeVal)
                                            .Where(o=>o.ErrorSourceId==inputtedESourceID)
                                            .Where(o=> hashkeyHostIdpair.Contains(new HashKeyHostId(){ hashkey=o.HashKey, hostid = o.HostId})).ToList();
```

but it errored out with {System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'RTM_DB.HashKeyHostId'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Answer (score 1):

> There's probably a very simple way of doing this that I'm not thinking of.

Yeah, there is

```
where hashKey.Contains(someValue) && hashKey.Contains(someOtherValue)
```

Comment: Please see the new edit for why I don't think this would work.

Comment: @Migit I wasn't suggesting you passed `hashKey` into both `Contains` calls, you can pass whatever you want in there. The point of my answer was to show you how to use `Contains` in the context of a multi-property check. The scenario you suggest in your edit, wouldn't you just do `hashKey.hashKey.Contains(thr.hashKey) && hashKey.hostId == thr.hostId`?

Comment: Your first hashkey is a list of HashKeyHostId objects.  You can't do a .contains on an object and have it translate to SQL.  For the .Contains to work with LINQ to SQL, it needs to be a List of primitives.  A list of objects you created yourself will error out with: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'RTM_DB.HashKeyHostId'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Comment: @Migit sorry, I missed that I assumed that `hashKey` was going to be a single object. In that case the check just becomes `hashKey.Any(x => x.hashKey.Contains(thr.hashKey) && x.hashKey.hostId == thr.hostId))`

Comment: I'll try that out.  In the past I've had lots of issues with .Any though. I'm giving it very large datasets and the .Any likes to error out saying it's nesting too deep

Comment: @Migit can't say I've came across that issue myself, however, you don't have any deep nesting in the context of this query (at least from the example you have shown).

Comment: That won't work either.  please see the second edit for a sample dataset.  The list is of HashKeyHostId.  that list contains 2 ints. There are no lists inside the list of HashKeyHostIds so you can't do a .contains on a single hashKey.  I tried doing this: "where hashkeyHostIdpair.Any(o=> o.hashkey==thr.HashKey && o.hostid==thr.HostId)", but that errored out with the same "Unable to create a constant value of type 'RTM_DB.HashKeyHostId'. Only primitive types are supported in this context." message.  It doesnt look like you can do a .Any or a .contains on a list of non-primitive types.

Comment: @Migit in that case the check you have is correct (i.e. remove `Contains` and use equals instead). What type is `HashKeyHostId`? It's obviously not an `int` - that's the cause of the error, not the condition itself. Unfortunately I can only answer questions based on the information provided and if it's not all there I have to make assumptions (which I have done).

Comment: The HashKeyHostId type is defined in the original post.  How I'm using that object is defined in the original post and again in Edit #2.

Comment: @Migit the error is because `HashKeyHostId` can't be translated to SQL so you can't use it in this context. You could possibly try `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>` or `List<int[]>` and treat `[0]` as `hashKey` and `[1]` as `hostId`.

Comment: Good suggestions, but unfortunately the keyvaluepair one returns the same error and the List<int[]> returns: "System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities".  I thought the List<int[]> would work!

Comment: @Migit hmm yeah same, that's unfortunate. Given you don't want to run this part in memory you may have to resort to a stored procedure.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Honestly, I've improved this method quite a bit already tonight.  Down from 38 seconds to 8 seconds.  The problem would be if we have some downtime and the program needs to play catch up. Then it'd be back up to the 38 seconds.  I guess this isn't the worst thing in the world...  1 slow run and it'd be back to normal

Comment: I already have the memory route coded.  It's threaded on a node with at least 24 processors so it doesn't take long to run.  I'm really just trying to reduce the load on our database.  Just doesn't seem effective to pull 200k+ records if you're only going to use 10k of those.

Comment: @Migit yep I agree, hence why I suggested the SP. If you can cope with an 8 second wait then stick with what you have. However, switching to an SP would give you various performance gains straight out the box *AND* only return the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this would maybe be what you want to do?

```
public void readRawThresholdsInList(int inputtedESourceID, DateTime maxDateTimeVal, List<int> hashKeys, List<int> hostIds)
{
    log.Info("Reading in raw thresholds from db");
    using (var db = new FAI())
    {
        var rths = (from thr in db.Thresholds
                    where thr.CalculatedDate == maxDateTimeVal
                    && thr.ErrorSourceId == inputtedESourceID
                    select thr);

        if (hashKeys != null && hashKeys.Count() > 0)
            rths = rths.Where(rth => hashKeys.Contains(rth.HashKey))

        if (hostIds != null && hostIds.Count() > 0)
            rths = rths.Where(rth => hostIds.Contains(rth.HostId)) // FieldName?

        rawThresholds = rths.ToList();
    }
    log.Info("Read in " + rawThresholds.Count() + " threshold records for error source id: " + inputtedESourceID + ".");
}
```

-- edit --

You could do something like this, but I wouldnt recommend it. Figure out a value which you can multiply the HashKey safely so HostId will always be in the last digits

```
var filters = new int[] { 100 * 100 + 1 , 101 * 100 + 5 }; // 10001 & 10105

var rths = (from rth in db.Thresholds
        where rth.CalculatedDate == maxDateTimeVal
        && rth.ErrorSourceId == inputtedESourceID
            && filters.Contains(rth.HashKey * 100 + rth.HostId)
            select rth).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe what you're suggesting is the same as what James suggested.  I don't think this would work.  It needs to be specified combinations of hashkeys and hostids, not any combination of the two. See the new edit.

Comment: Added a workaround which you could use in this particular case because both of your keys are integers.

Comment: My hashkeys actually take up the full range of an int32 so I can't use this method directly.  I tried casting everything to a double, but apparently there is no linq equivent of Convert.ToDouble() as this is erroring out:  where filter.Contains(Convert.ToDouble(thr.ParentErrorSignatureHashKey)*100000.0 + Convert.ToDouble(thr.HostId))   with a System.NotSupportedException exception

Comment: I changed it to where filter.Contains((double)(thr.ParentErrorSignatureHashKey)*100000.0 + (double)(thr.HostId)) and while this does appear be to work, it's taking way too long to run.  it's been going for the past 4 minute and it still hasn't returned.  If i make a view in the for this field it may go much faster, but I'll wait to see if anyone else has responses before going this route.

Comment: Tried it with Int64s and it also takes more time than without the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
List<HashKeyHostId> data = new List<HashKeyHostId>() {
    new HashKeyHostId { hashKey = 100, hostId = 1 },
    new HashKeyHostId { hashKey = 101, hostId = 5 }
}
```

You can use it in a contains like this:

```
<somequery>.Where(x => data.Contains(new HashKeyHostId { hashKey = x.HashKey, hostId = x.HostId }))
```

Note the use of the object initializer syntax instead of a constructor.

This should get translated to SQL with each item in the list being appended to the WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE ([t0].[HashKey] = @p0 AND [t0].[HostId] = @p1) OR
      ([t0].[HashKey] = @p2 AND [t0].[HostId] = @p3) OR ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail because `HashKeyHostId` can't be translated? Or does `Contains` do something clever that the other methods don't?

Comment: See edit #4.  It failed for the same reasons as the stuff James was suggesting.  Janne's suggestion sounded brilliant until I saw the run time :(

Comment: If the type is a POCO and you use the object initializer syntax, the query will understand it as a collection of properties. This could be done with anonymous types too.

Comment: @Migit You must be using EF, not linq to sql.

Comment: well crap.  I typoed the %#@* out of that.  yea, it's using EF

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this with EF?

Comment: @Migit Probably need to fall back on writing the sql manually and sending it with `db.Database.SqlQuery`.